# Why do I have Rails views overhead when handling API requests?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-api

I noticed in my logs that when I'm hitting API endpoints, the rails built in profiling is reporting that it is spending *some* time in "views" (heroku extra logging info removed):

```
[2021-08-06T21:04:20.864743 #32]  INFO -- : Started POST "/api/v1/places_in_bounds" for 24.184.254.41 at 2021-08-06 21:04:20 +0000
[2021-08-06T21:04:20.865565 #32]  INFO -- : Processing by Api::V1::PlacesController#in_bounds as */*
[2021-08-06T21:04:20.865629 #32]  INFO -- : Parameters: {"place"=>{"east"=>-38.800911000000006, "north"=>62.13593387702106, "south"=>-109.113411, "west"=>9.516666266458477}}
[2021-08-06T21:04:20.903245 #32]  INFO -- : Completed 200 OK in 37ms (Views: 26.8ms | ActiveRecord: 2.3ms | Allocations: 28475)
```

...but I'm not rendering any views! It's an API endpoint, not an `erb`. What's going on? Are my `jsonapi-serializer` serializers counted as views? Short of cracking open rails itself or profiling the ruby interpreter, it's not obvious to me what's going on. It's not a huge overhead (usually much less than 50%), but presumably the answer will be useful to others!

Answer (score 1):

Short answer is yes your JSON serialisers are counted, because you call `render` in your controller.

Both `ActionController::Base` and `ActionController::API` include `ActionController::Instrumentation`, which wraps `render` in a benchmark:

```rb
def render(*)
  render_output = nil
  self.view_runtime = cleanup_view_runtime do
    Benchmark.ms { render_output = super }
  end
  render_output
end
```

So, regardless of what format you are rendering, it captures and logs the runtime:

```rb
def log_process_action(payload) #:nodoc:
  messages, view_runtime = [], payload[:view_runtime]
  messages << ("Views: %.1fms" % view_runtime.to_f) if view_runtime
  messages
end
```